# 'Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value' with a function that just prints log

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

There have been like hundred similar questions and most with the answer suggesting to `return` something. I did that.

I learnt to implement cloud functions and wrote a function that does something on `write` event. That didn't work so I reduced the function recursively to come down to a single line of code that doesn't work either.

My code is as follows.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.demofunc = 
  functions.database
    .ref('/exportable/[some_long_ref]/newContacts')
    .onWrite(event => {
      console.log('Ok something changed')
      return true
    })
```

I expected this to work atleast but it didn't

I'm getting logs as follows

```
Function execution took 413 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
Function execution started

//[As you'd expect these logs are in reverse order.]
```

I also tried `return 0` but no success.

As you might have realized by now, this is my first attempt with Cloud functions and JS.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the log output include `Ok something changed`?  And is the function name on the left of log output `demofunc`?

Comment: Well, `Ok something changed` is not printed in log. The function name beside the error is my function's name which I have changed to `dempfunc` for stackoverflow purpose.

Comment: My guess is that you have not successfully deployed your revised code.  Try deploying again and look for `functions[yourFunctionName]: Successful update operation` in the deploy log.

Comment: I do see that every time I deploy with edits followed by `Deploy complete!`. I guess that is not an issue. I will still try to write a new function all-to-gather and see if that was the case but I strongly believe that is not.

Comment: I copied and ran the code you posted:  no error and log output contains 
 `Ok something changed`.  I suspect you are not actually deploying the posted code.  Maybe another index.js file?

Comment: My bad. Let me try and figure out if there is any issue with cloud-functions package on my local system.

Comment: @BobSnyder thanks for letting me know there was no issue with the code. I reinstalled functions package and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved the issue by just reinstalling firebase-functions package on my system. I remember I had an issue while installation which I ignored and that was the same thing that was hindering.

I was getting a log in my local console saying `Deployed successfully` but it was actually not deploying successfully.

Thanks Bob (in comments under question) for letting me know there was no issue with the code.